# python recursion function rewind automatically

Tags: python, function

```
def s(text):
    def rec(string, store):
        if len(store) < 20:
            store += f"/{string}"
            print("store -- ", store)
            rec(string, store)
            print("store !! ", store)
            return store
        else:
            print("end")
            return store
    return rec(text, '')


d = s("xxx")
print(d)
```

output : -

```
store --  /xxx
store --  /xxx/xxx
store --  /xxx/xxx/xxx
store --  /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx
store --  /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx
end
store !!  /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx
store !!  /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx
store !!  /xxx/xxx/xxx
store !!  /xxx/xxx
store !!  /xxx
/xxx
```

i run the function when recursion function run after that it should be return the function but it it run automatically in rewind.
why it happening.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, or what that function is supposed to do, but you should probably do something with the result of `rec(string, store)`

Comment: actually i create the situation as i have in my project. so  i need the output ( store --  /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx ) in my code but it gives only this - /xxx

Comment: Still not clear. Maybe you want `res = rec(...)` and then `return res` in the `if` block?

Answer (score 0):

String in python are immutable. When you do `store += f"/{string}"`, you are not appending to store, you are actually creating a new buffer containing the concatenation of the previous buffer of store and `f"/{string}"`. Then, when you up the stack after `rec` returned, store has not been modified by recursive calls (note also that when you call a function in python, you pass a copy of the reference to each arguments).

To get the desired output, you have to return the new value of store. (or wrap store in a list that is mutable)

This way :

```
def s(text):
    def rec(string, store):
        if len(store[0]) < 20:
            store[0] += f"/{string}"
            print("store -- ", store[0])
            rec(string, store)
            print("store !! ", store[0])
            # No return needed since the list is modified in recursive calls
        else:
            print("end")
            # No return needed either (anyway, it already has its final value...)
    store = [''] # <---- Need to create a mutable object to act as a "pointer"(-ish)
    rec(text, store)
    return store[0] # <---- ...And we return the pointed object. Don't be mistaken, this object is NOT the same as the initial ''. However, the list holding it is the same.

d = s("xxx")
print(d)
```

Or this way :

```
def s(text):
    def rec(string, store):
        if len(store) < 20:
            store += f"/{string}"
            print("store -- ", store)
            store = rec(string, store) # <---- Here I update store with the result of the recursive call
            print("store !! ", store)
            return store
        else:
            print("end")
            return store
    return rec(text, '')


d = s("xxx")
print(d)
```

Comment: thank you for replying.i get the point and is really help me. thank you so much